# Angular Meteor objects not acting as expected

Tags: angular-meteor

I am working with Angular Meteor and am having an issue with my objects/arrays.  I have this code:

```
angular.module("learn").controller("CurriculumDetailController", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteor',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $meteor){
    $scope.curriculum = $meteor.object(CurriculumList, $stateParams.curriculumId);

    $scope.resources = _.map($scope.curriculum.resources, function(obj) {
      return ResourceList.findOne({_id:obj._id})
    });

    console.log($scope.resources)
  }]);
```

I am attempting to iterate over 'resources', which is a nested array in the curriculum object, look up each value in the 'ResourceList' collection, and return the new array in the scope.

Problem is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.  When I load up the page and access it through a UI-router link.  I get the array as expected.  But if the page is refreshed, $scope.resources is an empty array.

My thought is there is something going on with asynchronous calls but have not been able for find a solution.  I still have the autopublish package installed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out [publish composites](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) on atmosphere, you will be able to get this all done server side and save a lot of problems. If you'd like a demo I'll write it up as an answer. The issue you're having here is an issue with angular and page refreshing the controller properly.

Comment: Ill see where I can take this, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @TjGienger.  Thanks for the suggestion.  It looks like this can do what I need, but I am not sure how to accomplish it.  In the examples, they are returning a cursor using find (with multiple posts for example).  They then iterate over those and do what they want.  In contrast, I am looking to findOne and then iterate over a nested field in that one document, mapping each one to a document in another collection.  Is there a way to do this with the publish composites package?  A demo would be amazing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to do is return a cursor containing all the information you want, then you can work with $meteor.object on the client side if you like. Normally, publishComposite would look something like this: (I don't know what your curriculum.resources looks like)

Use this method if the curriculum.resources has only ONE id:

```
// this takes the place of the publish method
Meteor.publishComposite('curriculum', function(id) {
  return {
      find: function() {

        // Here you are getting the CurriculumList based on the id, or whatever you want
        return CurriculumList.find({_id: id});
      },
      children: [
        {
          find: function(curr) {
            // (curr) will be each of the CurriculumList's found from the parent query
            // Normally you would do something like this:
            return ResourceList.find(_id: curr.resources[0]._id);
          }
        }
      ]
    }
})
```

This method if you have multiple resources:

However, since it looks like your curriculum is going to have a resources list with one or many objects with id's then we need to build the query before returning anything. Try something like:

```
// well use a function so we can send in an _id
Meteor.publishComposite('curriculum', function(id){
    // we'll build our query before returning it.
    var query = {
        find: function() {
            return CurriculumList.find({_id: id});
        }
    };        

    // now we'll fetch the curriculum so we can access the resources list
    var curr = CurriculumList.find({_id: id}).fetch();

    // this will pluck the ids from the resources and place them into an array
    var rList = _.pluck(curr.resources, '_id');

    // here we'll iterate over the resource ids and place a "find" object into the query.children array.

    query.children = [];

    _.each(rList, function(id) {
        var childObj = {
            find: function() {
                return ResourceList.find({_id: id});
            }
        };
        query.children.push(childObj)
    })

    return query;
});
```

So what *should* happen here (I didn't test) is with one publish function you will be getting the Curriculum you want, plus all of it's resourceslist children.

Now you will have access to these on the client side.

```
$scope.curriculum = $meteor.object(CurriculumList, $stateParams.curriculumId);
// collection if more than one, object if only one.
$scope.resources = $meteor.collection(ResoursesList, false);
```

This was thrown together somewhat quickly so I apologize if it doesn't work straight off, any trouble I'll help you fix.